# Referencing yourself

Tags: discussion

Being the friendly chap that I am I have worked on fitness wiki's on other sites to produce well rounded answers that are well researched. I spent a lot of time doing these and am happy with the results.

If I were to copy-paste that information it would be deemed "copying" by Stack's rules as the wiki does not define an author (it's not a traditional wiki, more of a FAQ).

What is the best way to reference this information in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to provide a summary answer, citing the pertinent parts (You could also disclose that you are a contributor), and a link to the site if they want to read further. Pretty much the same as using any external site as the basis for an answer.